# error when reading headers from a file - requests

Tags: python, request

hello I am trying to read the headers of a file to use the query in the requests, I read that to send the headers I could send a dictionary. everything seems to be correct but i always get an error

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://192.168.98.106/login'

with open('data.txt.bak') as f:
   data = json.loads(f.read())


headers_dict = {

    "Host": "192.168.98.106",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"       
}

def get_headers_as_dict(headers: str) -> dict:
   dic = {}
   for line in headers.split("\n"):
       if line.startswith(("GET", "POST")):
           continue
       point_index = line.find(":")
       dic[line[:point_index].strip()] = line[point_index+1:].strip()
   return dic

with open('headers.txt') as f:
    headers_file = f.read()

print(get_headers_as_dict(headers_file))
print(headers_dict)

proxies = {"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"}
r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers_file, proxies=proxies)
```

error:

```
File "/home/user/documents/test.py", line 44, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers_file, proxies=proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 317, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 449, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Thank you so much

Comment: `requests.post` argument `headers` expect a dict, not a `str` (as returned by `f.read()`.

Comment: But when the type method gives me that dict, could you please tell me what the error is?

Comment: `headers_file = f.read()` is a `str`. You then further pass it to `r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers_file, proxies=proxies)` which expects a `dict` for argument `headers`. That's the error.